# Getting each variable from an array

Tags: php, mysql

I am  trying to retrieve tags that are associated with a society. The code below works, but it is only retrieving the first tag and not the rest in the table.

```
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$society = $_SESSION['society'];

$soc_q = mysql_query("SELECT socID, creator, socName, type, datetime
     FROM societies.society WHERE socName = '$society'");
$soc_row = mysql_fetch_array($soc_q, MYSQL_ASSOC);


$tag_q = mysql_query("SELECT society.socID, tagID, name
     FROM societies.society
     INNER JOIN societies.tags ON society.socID = tags.socID
     WHERE society.socID = '$soc_row[socID]'");
$tag_row = mysql_fetch_array($tag_q, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$the_tags = $tag_row['name'];

if (!@$_SESSION['existing_tags']) {
    $_SESSION['existing_tags'] = $the_tags;
}

$existing_tags = $_SESSION['existing_tags'];
$tags = explode(' ', $the_tags);

// ajax
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && @$_GET['tag']) {
    $match = array();
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        if (stripos($tag, $_GET['tag']) === 0) {
            $match[] = $tag;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($match);

    exit;
```

Comment: Either it "works" or it "doesn't work". Both can't be true.

Comment: where did I say it "doesn't work"?

Comment: Why are you here if there is no problem with that code? Yet you said "The code below works".

Comment: so you stopped reading after i said: "the code below works" without continuing after the word "but"? I am here because there are people here who will help out, just to answer your question.

Comment: No, I continued reading, and then posted a comment remarking on the 100% contradiction in the sentence you're talking about. As I said before, it either works or it doesn't; pick one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to load tags in loop like this (get each row):

```
$the_tags = array();
while( $tag_row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $tag_q)){
    $the_tags[] = $tag_row['name'];
}
```

#### Edit: using GROUP BY

If you are willing to play with mySQL and element grouping you may use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) (if you need only tag names):

```
$tag_q = mysql_query("
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT tags.name SEPARATOR ', ') as `tags`
     FROM societies.society
     INNER JOIN societies.tags ON society.socID = tags.socID
     WHERE society.socID = '$soc_row[socID]'
     GROUP BY NULL");
$tag_row = mysql_fetch_array($tag_q, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$tag_names = explode( ', ', $tag_row['tags']);
```

The code above isn't that useful, but when you'll combine it with your first query, you'll get:

```
$soc_q = mysql_query("SELECT socID, creator, socName, type, datetime,
     GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT tags.name SEPARATOR ', ') as `tags`
     FROM society
     LEFT JOIN societies On societies.socID = society.socID
     LEFT JOIN tags ON societies.tagsID = tags.socID
     WHERE socName = '$society'
     GROUP_BY society.id");
$soc_row = mysql_fetch_array($soc_q, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

<sub>Note: prefixing tables with database names makes your code hard to read because once you're doing that, other time not.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry about the confusing code, but glad you understood. Much appreciated.